# Is it possible to get the address of memory in under memory?

Tags: c++

I know that we can read the location/position of a variable and its value in the memory but I want to go more deeper to see where is this memory address located if it is possible.
In my case **0x61fe09** is the memory address for **a** and what is the memory address for **0x61fe09**.

code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 42;
  int* adress_of_a = &a;
  int** adress_of_adress_of_a = &adress_of_a;
  cout << " a = " << a << " at memory address = " << &adress_of_adress_of_a << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223434/discussion-on-question-by-indiana-jones-is-it-possible-to-get-the-address-of-mem).

Answer (score 3):

There's no memory address for `&a` because it's not stored in memory.

You could store it in memory like so:

```
int* pointer_to_a = &a;
```

Now you can print `&pointer_to_a` to see the address where you stored `&a`.